# How to make columns list on pyspark from a other pys[park dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Here's my code

```
list_selected_apps_id = ['146', '929']
fd_orion_apps = fd_orion_apps.groupBy('msisdn', 'apps_id').pivot('apps_id').count().select('msisdn', *list_selected_apps_id).fillna(0)
fd_orion_apps.show(truncate=False)
```

I will switch the `list_selected_apps_id` to all columns from `parameter` dataframe (200 + columns)

Here's the `parameter` dataframe

```
DataFrame[_c0: string, 2853: string, 1864: string, 2658: string, 11187: string, 2874: string, 1352: string, 12871: string, 8602: string, 2844: string, 10444: string, 10250: string, 10003: string, 20083: string, 11583: string, 2870: string, 1706: string, 45220: string, 21422: string, 11285: string, 31570: string, 6356: string, 6673: string, 4160: string, 10848: string, 10374: string, 11918: string, 30375: string, 1055: string, 1271: string, 6278: string, 21361: string, 10184: string, 2004: string, 2170: string, 1472: string, 7011: string, 2460: string, 13108: string, 30972: string, 324: string, 12618: string, 13541: string, 2524: string, 14424: string, 6651: string, 10070: string, 10513: string, 31564: string, 392: string, 5405: string, 5167: string, 1884: string, 45243: string, 2312: string, 2115: string, 45027: string, 18: string, 13297: string, 17066: string, 13756: string, 7308: string, 31602: string, 32339: string, 10477: string, 16791: string, 31165: string, 12251: string, 33246: string, 8601: string, 7084: string, 20277: string, 15975: string, 12523: string, 21072: string, 4208: string, 1731: string, 3431: string, 45208: string, 10579: string, 15306: string, 45112: string, 20009: string, 45264: string, 2803: string, 3503: string, 31623: string, 21404: string, 1411: string, 19077: string, 3417: string, 32684: string, 31730: string, 11799: string, 6828: string, 12068: string, 32628: string, 13317: string, 21483: string, 15852: string, 15257: string, 17453: string, 11646: string, 8422: string, 8239: string, 12434: string, 21492: string, 7411: string, 1732: string, 11696: string, 280: string, 30634: string, 12148: string, 45216: string, 10860: string, 21505: string, 11532: string, 10689: string, 32759: string, 45164: string, 10911: string, 31109: string, 12004: string, 11331: string, 3967: string, 10764: string, 272: string, 19635: string, 274: string, 10476: string, 12006: string, 21232: string, 15914: string, 12812: string, 12233: string, 7486: string, 15942: string, 10869: string, 7537: string, 32175: string, 21479: string, 31856: string, 31955: string, 13338: string, 10339: string, 13333: string, 11173: string, 8142: string, 8496: string, 11299: string, 8282: string, 20067: string, 12132: string, 21493: string, 13667: string, 11881: string, 13125: string, 7595: string, 21393: string, 13695: string, 31662: string, 31752: string, 13043: string, 2626: string, 31244: string, 1676: string, 4532: string, 2250: string, 34: string, 31295: string, 12: string, 13550: string, 31728: string, 17747: string, 900: string, 30363: string, 12636: string, 14047: string, 10418: string, 20151: string, 32622: string, 13159: string, 13248: string, 6934: string, 6820: string, 45008: string, 31434: string, 12458: string, 12575: string, 2801: string, 31059: string, 11885: string, 31035: string, 16520: string, 4467: string, 13320: string, 12481: string, 15001: string, 45004: string, 13606: string, 13249: string, 13648: string, 30991: string, 13684: string, 12832: string, 17209: string, 12497: string, 19719: string, 1858: string, 12845: string, 12043: string, 13692: string, 31258: string, 11996: string, 21488: string, 5584: string, 17239: string, 4800: string, 4422: string, 16747: string, 51: string, 12732: string, 11054: string, 13698: string, 2246: string, 10885: string, 11708: string, 3988: string, 20053: string, 8472: string, 6942: string, 45012: string, 30977: string, 11629: string, 10843: string, 12820: string, 15995: string, 15302: string, 10131: string, 33028: string, 32167: string, 7901: string, 6318: string, 1941: string, 10526: string, 1577: string, 13515: string, 16338: string]
```

I don't want to make  `list_selected_apps_id` manually

Comment: Question is vague. Are you able to provide input data frame and expected output?

Comment: I will switch the `list_selected_apps_id` to all columns from `parameter` dataframe (200 + columns), it is clear enough @wwnde

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `fd_orion_apps = fd_orion_apps.groupBy('msisdn', 'apps_id').pivot('apps_id').count().select('msisdn', *parameter.columns).fillna(0)
fd_orion_apps.show(truncate=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

`fd_orion_apps = fd_orion_apps.groupBy('msisdn', 'apps_id').pivot('apps_id').count().select('msisdn', *parameter.columns).fillna(0) fd_orion_apps.show(truncate=False)`

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1381.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`8602`' given input columns: [7537, 7011, 2658, 3582, 12120, 31049, 35010, 16615, 10003, 15067, 1914, 1436, 6032, 422, 10636, 1038 ...

Comment: Basically after grouping 'fd_orion_apps' don't have all the column that `parameter` have, I clarify the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925588/make-a-not-avaliable-columnn-in-pyspark-dataframe-full-of-zero

Comment: That's why I advised question was vague. If new df doesn't have all columns that are in parameter it will fail. If you want to know what columns to retain you have to intersect the columns from each of the df. What's the rationale of doing so if you will retain all the columns in the new df anyway?