# Make a not available column in PySpark dataframe full of zero

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, fill

I have a script which is currently running in sample dataframe. Here's my code:

```py
fd_orion_apps = fd_orion_apps.groupBy('msisdn', 'apps_id').pivot('apps_id').count().select('msisdn', *parameter_cut.columns).fillna(0)
```

After pivoting, probably some columns in `parameter_cut` are not available on df `fd_orion_apps`, and it will give the error like this:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1381.select.
> : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`8602`' given input columns: [7537, 7011, 2658, 3582, 12120, 31049, 35010, 16615, 10003, 15067, 1914, 1436, 6032, 422, 10636, 10388, 877,...

Comment: That being the case you can `fd_orion_apps = fd_orion_apps.groupBy('msisdn', 'apps_id').pivot('apps_id').count().fillna(0)` and drop the columns you dont want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the `select` into a different step. Then you will be able to use a conditional expression together with list comprehension.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

fd_orion_apps = fd_orion_apps.groupBy('msisdn', 'apps_id').pivot('apps_id').count()
fd_orion_apps = fd_orion_apps.select(
    'msisdn',
    *[c if c in fd_orion_apps.columns else F.lit(0).alias(c) for c in parameter_cut.columns]
)
```